# Listbox CSS markups not working and divs not displaying side by side

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I've got a couple of issues with the below code. First, the CSS styles I'm specifying for my 2 listboxes aren't working...basically none of the CSS styles for the listboxes are applied. The second issue is that I want my 2 main divs in the panel 'pnlSelAccounts' to display side by side but they are being stacked on top of each other. The first div should contain the the first textbox, label, button and the 2 list boxes and the second should contain the 2 smaller panels along with their contents. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<style type="text/css">
    body 
    {
        background-color: #232323;
        font-family: Knowledge Regular;
    }
    legend
    {
        color: #D4D4D4;
    }
    .UpperPanel
    {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .RightPanel
    {
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .ListBox_Default
    {
        color: #D4D4D4;
        background-color: #232323;
        border: solid 2px #000000;
        padding-left: 20px;
        height: 250px;      
        width: 250px;
    }        
    fieldset 
    {
        border: solid 2px #000000;
        width: 100%;
    }        
    .DisplayTextBoxStyle
    {
        color: #00FFFF;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 0px solid;
        width: 65%;
    }
    .InputTextBoxStyle
    {
        color: #D4D4D4;
        background-color: #232323;
        border: solid 2px #000000;          
    }     
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_header
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_tab
    {
        color: #FF9900;
    }         
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_outer
    {
        color: #D4D4D4;
        font-family: Knowledge Regular;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        border:solid 2px #000000;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_inner
    {
        border-color: #666;
        font-family: Knowledge Regular;
        color: #666;
        padding: 3px 10px 2px 0px;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_outer
    {
        background-color:#525252;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_inner
    {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_outer
    {
        font-family: Knowledge Bold;
        background-color: #525252;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner
    {
        font-family: Knowledge Bold;
        color: #000;
        border-color: #333;
    }
    .TabStyle .ajax__tab_body
    {
        font-family: Knowledge Regular;
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #D4D4D4;
        background-color: #525252;
        border-top-width: 0;
        border: solid 2px #000000;
        border-top-color: #000000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

   </style>

   <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Image ID="imgTRLogo" runat="server" style="z-index: 1;"
            ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png"/>

    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
            style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 40px; position: absolute; width: 1009px; margin-top: 0px; font-family: 'Knowledge Bold'; color: #FF9900; font-size: large;" 
            Text="ORDER FORM GENERATOR">
        </asp:Label>
    </p>

    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tabMainContainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 20px; top: 100px; position: absolute;" CssClass="TabStyle">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Build New Order Form" ID="tbnAcctData" TabIndex="0">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelAccounts" runat="server" GroupingText="Select Accounts" CssClass="UpperPanel"
                        Style="width: 100%" HorizontalAlign="Left">

                    <div>

                        <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px;">

                            <asp:Label ID="lblSearchAcctNo" runat="server" Text="Account Number:"/>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchAcctNo" runat="server" CssClass="InputTextBoxStyle"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchAccts" runat="server" Text="Search" />

                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div>

                            <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">

                                <asp:Label ID="lblChildAccts" runat="server" Text="Location Accounts"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:ListBox ID="lstSubAccounts" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssStyle="ListBox_Default"/>

                            </div>

                            <div>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblLEAccts" runat="server" Text="Legal Entities"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:ListBox ID="lstLEAccts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssStyle="ListBox_Default"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLEAddress" runat="server" GroupingText="Legal Entity Address"
                            style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; width: 50%;">

                            <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">

                                <asp:Label ID="lblLEName" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="Legal Entity Name:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLEName" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStreet" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="Street Address:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLEStreet" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCityStateZip" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="City, State & Zipcode:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLECityStateZip" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="Country:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLECountry" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>

                            </div>

                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMSC" runat="server" GroupingText="Main Sales Contact"
                            style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; width: 50%;">

                            <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">

                                <asp:Label ID="lblMSCSalutation" runat="server" Style="width: 20%" Text="Salutation:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMSCSalutation" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />        
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMSCFirstName" runat="server" Style="width: 20%" Text="First Name:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMSCFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />        
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMSCLastName" runat="server" Style="width: 20%" Text="Last Name:"/>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMSCLastName" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayTextBoxStyle"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCustomMSC" runat="server" Text="Select Main Sales Contact"/>
                                <br />

                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlCustomerMSC" runat="server" GroupingText="Main Sales Contact"
                                    style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; width: 50%;">

                                    <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">

                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustMSCSalutation" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="Salutation:"/>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpMCSSalutation" runat="server" />
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustMSCFirstName" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="First Name:"/>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustMSCFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="InputTextBoxStyle"/>
                                        <br />        
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustMSCLasstName" runat="server" Style="width: 30%" Text="Last Name:"/>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustMSCLastName" runat="server" CssClass="InputTextBoxStyle"/>

                                    </div>

                                </asp:Panel>

                            </div>

                        </asp:Panel>

                    </div>                        

                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelectProducts" runat="server" GroupingText="Select Products" CssClass="RightPanel">

                </asp:Panel>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tbnGeneratedForms" runat="server" HeaderText="Generated Forms" TabIndex="1">
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or CodePen? This is a lot to parse.

Comment: Sorry I've never used those before. Did you just want me to add the code to CodePen? If yes, then it's available at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEdqr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `CSSClass`, not `CSSStyle`.

Currently, you're outputting

```
style="ListBox_Default"
```

CSSClass will output

```
class="ListBox_Default"
```

Comment: Thanks, that added most of the CSS markups to the listboxes. For some reason is looks like the border markup (border: solid 2px #000000;) wasn't applied. Any ideas what that would happen? What about my issue with the divs being stacked instead of positioned side by side?

Comment: There are a few issues. Border should be size, style, color, not style, size, color, also you have border-color without size in some places.

Answer (score 0):

The issue related to positioning the divs side by side was solved by using 'float: left' & 'float: right' on left & right div respectively.